# How to divide polyline layer using shared vertex

Tags: qgis, python

I have a polyline layer with 1638 features representing a road network. Each feature is a line segment which may or may not share one or both endpoints (vertices) with an adjacent line segment.

I would like to somehow aggregate these segments where the vertices are coincident, where there are 4 features representing end-to-end polyline where the vertices of each segment touch, these should be aggregated into one feature.

How can I do this within **QGIS**?

I have tried `SinglePart to MultiPart tool` but this accomplishes something similar to a general dissolve where the individual LineString features become one big MultiLineString and I only get one record in my attribute table.

Instead, I would like for the LineStrings to get aggregated into yet longer LineStrings where coincident vertices occur. I am also open to python solutions, notably using the qgis library.

**EDIT**

It turns out that the correct sequence is:

- Dissolve
- MultiPart to SinglePart

Which also illustrates that there is a difference between Dissolve and SinglePart to MultiPart tools as addressed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123722/singleparts-to-multipart-vs-dissolve). But unfortunately you run into another problem as shown in the following figure:

[image]

The line segments coincide at exactly the same point as proven by `exportToWkt()` method ([see this question also](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296024/get-selected-feature-geometry-using-qgis-api))

```
371119.89580000005662441 4688236.42149999924004078
371119.89580000005662441 4688236.42149999924004078
371119.89580000005662441 4688236.42149999924004078
```

Yet somehow the algorithm gets "confused" here and isn't sure which lines to connect, (1 and 3, leaving 2 out? 2 and 3, leaving 1 out). The algorithm seems to also separate where more than 2 lines contain the same coordinate.

In my version I would like it to default to the "longest" line, such that 1 and 3 are merged into one feature, leaving 2 out (1 and 3 add up to a greater length than any other combination).

Is there an "enhanced multipart to singlepart tool that can help me accomplish this?