# Getting selected feature geometry using QGIS API?

Tags: pyqgis, geometry

I want to get the geometry for a selected feature using QGIS API. When extracting geometry for unselected features this is what I typically do:

```
l = iface.activeLayer()
fs = l.getFeatures() #returns QgsFeatureIterator object
f = fs.next() #returns next QgsFeature object
g = g.geometry() # returns geometry object
```

I tried doing something similar with only selected features but ran into a problem:

```
l = iface.activeLayer()
s = l.selectedFeatures() #returns QgsFeature object
g = s.geometry() #throws error. Also dir(s) confirms that s has no geometry() method
```

How come `s` has no method `geometry()`?

Isn't it an instance of the same class as `f` in the first example?

How can I extract geometry for only the selected feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `s` is not a `QgsFeature` in the strictest sense, because you can have multiple selected features. I'm confused here because I only have one, but once you do the following:

```
g  = s[0].geometry()
```

It should index into your selected feature subset, in this case extracting the first (and only) list item, and return the `QgsGeometry` object.

Comment: Yes that's because `selectedFeatures()` returns a list of selected features as QgsFeature. If you have only one selected feature, il returns a list of one QgsFeature.